# How to position silverlight OOB top and left position during runtime?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-oob

In silverlight out of browser, after login from the silverlight login page, I would like to adjust the position of it. I have tried my luck setting Application.Current.MainWindow.Left and Application.Current.MainWindow.Top but unfortunately it is ignored.

According to MSDN:

> You can set this property at run time only if WindowStartupLocation is
>   set to Manual. Additionally, you can set this property at run time
>   only before the end of the Application.Startup event, after which any
>   changes are ignored. For example, you can save the current value to
>   isolated storage in an Application.Exit event handler, and restore the
>   value in an Application.Startup event handler.

I have to adjust the position during runtime but not before application startup.
What to do now?

Comment: you should visit :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187431/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-set-host-window-size/14038629#14038629

Comment: i have visited this site and it isn't helpful to the issue im facing. I want to adjust the position but not the size of the mainwindow

Comment: check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592447/can-i-change-silverlight-out-of-browser-settings-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try This Way:

1 . Click On Sliverlight Project

2 . Select Properties option

3 . Select First tab option Like Silverlight

4 . Click On Out-Of-Browser setting Option

5 . Set the window size, window title or window position etc......

[image]

Comment: it only able to set and fix the side when the application start up. However, I would like to adjust the window POSITION during runtime

Comment: in outofBrowser option you should check option for set position

Comment: I believe when the application is started up, it will be positioned at top and left 10. 
so after the application is started up,and due to some process, I have to change the top and left position to 60 and 100 respectively, what should I do?

Comment: I think that is not possible dude!!

Comment: that was my question!! sad to hear it is not possible

Comment: Dont worry nothing is impossible Give me some time for rnd

Comment: looking forward to hear the answer from you

Comment: are you Follow MVVM or Prism ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40725/discussion-between-jignesh-raj-and-den)